# Render total for specific quote

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

I want to display th quote total using magneto native rendere but it is not display anything. Actually I want to display it as pdf which I'm generating for a specific quote not for checkout cart. To do that I have written below code but it does not work. Any one please help me.

Below is my `total.phtml`

```
<?php
  $quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->load('121');
  Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->setQuote($quote)->saveQuote();
  echo "<pre>";print_r(Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getTotals());echo "</pre>";exit;


?>
<?php if(!Mage::getModel('masteradmin/session')->getIsstarPrice()):?>
  <?php if ($this->canApplyMsrp()): ?>
    <div class="cart-msrp-totals"><?php echo $this->__('ORDER TOTAL WILL BE DISPLAYED BEFORE YOU SUBMIT THE ORDER'); ?></div>
  <?php else: ?>
    <table id="shopping-cart-totals-table" style="border-bottom:1px solid #000;padding-bottom:10px">
        <col />
        <col width="1" />

        <tbody>
            <?php echo $this->renderTotals(); ?>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <?php echo $this->renderTotals('footer'); ?>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
  <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Any hint what does not work?

Comment: It gives 500 internal server error.